# Plesk managed server is spamming - how to detect the causing source?

Tags: email, plesk, spam

I am running a Debian 8.9‬ root server for me and some clients which is managed by Plesk Onyx Version 17.5.3 Update #28.

Maybe 2 weeks ago I noticed the first "Undelivered Mail Returned to Sender" when I sent mails to a known recipient. In the meantime the problem spread and my IP is now flagged as spam from at least 1 public spam directory (CBL).

So it's obvious that the server is sending spam. But how can I detect the causing source? Could be an old WordPress installation from one of the clients, maybe a weak password from on of the clients mailboxes.

I took a look in the maillog file, but it's too many information to see a suspicious action.

What can I do now?

Answer (score 0):

Spam may be sent by some mailbox on a domain, or by PHP script.

To find out what domain is causing the issue, install [Outgoing Mail Control in Plesk.](https://docs.plesk.com/en-US/onyx/administrator-guide/website-management/mail-settings/limiting-outgoing-mail.73362/). More details about this are available [here.](https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001652774-How-to-find-the-source-of-spam)

If it's a PHP script, there is a way to track it down using details [here for Postfix mail server](https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/213914405) and [here for Qmail](https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/213959565).

Comment: I already did all of this.
The outgoing mail control didn't show any suspicious.

The mail.send log is still empty even when I sent a mail using PHP myself. I can see the additional header within the test mail, but log is still empty.

What now?!